# Quote marks in bash file created in Python

Tags: python, string, bash, pandas, quotes

I'm using Python and Pandas to write multiple bash scripts. I have a pandas.Series containing the script. Simplified::

```
script = pd.Series([
'#!/bin/bash',
'#SBATCH --output "/home/path/output_filename.out"'
])
```

I then use `script.to_csv('script_file.bat',index=False)` to create the file.
The output file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
"#SBATCH --output ""/home/path/output_filename.out"""
```

I have tried all the suggestions here  [Python - Using quotation marks inside quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050355/python-using-quotation-marks-inside-quotation-marks) (triple quotes, single and double quotes (as shown in the example) , escaping the quotemarks), as well as making the quoted text a variable, but none works.

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21147058/pandas-to-csv-output-quoting-issue

Comment: Yup, that's perfect

Comment: "I'm using ... Pandas to write ... bash scripts." O_o Bash scripts are plain text. Is using Pandas really that much help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to explicitly specify quoting for [`df.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
import csv

pd.DataFrame(script).to_csv("test.sh", index=False, header=False,
                            quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

> #!/bin/bash
> #SBATCH --output "/home/path/output_filename.out"
```