# How I can put a single `"` in my csv using python and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, quotes, double-quotes

I am working in python on processing multiple excel files in one csv to upload this csv in another corporate program. One of the columns must be with double quotes. Example:
Customer number:
"03939930303"
"22489903040"
I am trying to append quotes using code like this

```
df['customer_number'] = '"'+ df['customer_number'] + '"'
```

but after this in my csv file i have this:

```
"""03939930303"""
"""22489903040"""
```

i need only one quote, not three.
Things that I already tried:

```
csv.QUOTE_NONE
```

doesn't work because I have another heading that should look like `"customer name"` and around 15+ headings that should be with quotes.

How I can put a single `"` in my csv using python and pandas?

UPDATE:

CSV CONTENT:

> N,empty,NUMBER,"('Something Something', 'sumAve')","('Something Something', 'sumTr')","('Something Something', 'sumPL')","('Something Something', 'DATA (IB 35%)')","('Characteristic', 'sumAve')","('Characteristic', 'sumTr')","('Characteristic', 'sumPL')","('Characteristic', 'DATA (IB 35%)')","('Finance', 'sumAve')","('Finance', 'sumTr')","('Finance', 'sumPL')","('Finance', 'DATA (IB 35%)')","('Food', 'sumAve')","('Food', 'sumTr')","('Food', 'sumPL')","('Food', 'DATA (IB 35%)')","('Text', 'sumAve')","('Text', 'sumTr')","('Text', 'sumPL')","('Text', 'DATA (IB 35%)')","('Due", Due 2', 'sumAve')","('Due", Due 2', 'sumTr')","('Due", Due 2', 'sumPL')","('Due", Due 2', 'DATA (IB 35%)')","('BAG', 'sumAve')","('BAG', 'sumTr')","('BAG', 'sumPL')","('BAG', 'DATA (IB 35%)')","('OIL', 'sumAve')","('OIL', 'sumTr')","('OIL', 'sumPL')","('OIL', 'DATA (IB 35%)')","('Labour', 'sumAve')","('Labour', 'sumTr')","('Labour', 'sumPL')","('Labour', 'DATA (IB 35%)')","('Service', 'sumAve')","('Service', 'sumTr')","('Service', 'sumPL')","('Service', 'DATA (IB 35%)')",City,Region,CODE 1,CODE 2
>   ,,0,1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000,7000,8000,9000,10000,11000,12000,13000,14000,15000,16000,17000,18000,19000,20000,21000,22000,23000,24000,25000,26000,27000,28000,29000,30000,31000,32000,33000,34000,35000,36000,37000,38000,39000,40000,NEW YORK,0,N6UJ9A00C0J8,TOTO africa 1
>   ,,00,41000,42000,43000,44000,45000,46000,47000,48000,49000,50000,51000,52000,53000,54000,55000,56000,57000,58000,59000,60000,61000,62000,63000,64000,65000,66000,67000,68000,69000,70000,71000,72000,73000,74000,75000,76000,77000,78000,79000,80000,NEW YORK,0,N6UJ9A013229,TOTO africa 2
>   ,,001,81000,82000,83000,84000,85000,86000,87000,88000,89000,90000,91000,92000,93000,94000,95000,96000,97000,98000,99000,100000,101000,102000,103000,104000,105000,106000,107000,108000,109000,110000,111000,112000,113000,114000,115000,116000,117000,118000,119000,120000,NEW YORK,0,N6UJ9A00YFYS,TOTO africa 3
>   ,,1234567890,121000,122000,123000,124000,125000,126000,127000,128000,129000,130000,131000,132000,133000,134000,135000,136000,137000,138000,139000,140000,141000,142000,143000,144000,145000,146000,147000,148000,149000,150000,151000,152000,153000,154000,155000,156000,157000,158000,159000,160000,NEW YORK,0,N6UJ9A00LR36,"toto ""africa 4"""
>   ,,123456789012,161000,162000,163000,164000,165000,166000,167000,168000,169000,170000,171000,172000,173000,174000,175000,176000,177000,178000,179000,180000,181000,182000,183000,184000,185000,186000,187000,188000,189000,190000,191000,192000,193000,194000,195000,196000,197000,198000,199000,200000,NEW YORK,0,N6UJ9A00G1YH,toto africa
>   ,,0234567891,201000,202000,203000,204000,205000,206000,207000,208000,209000,210000,211000,212000,213000,214000,215000,216000,217000,218000,219000,220000,221000,222000,223000,224000,225000,226000,227000,228000,229000,230000,231000,232000,233000,234000,235000,236000,237000,238000,239000,240000,NEW YORK,0,N6UJ9A00C0J9,toto africa
>   ,,023456789012,241000,242000,243000,244000,245000,246000,247000,248000,249000,250000,251000,252000,253000,254000,255000,256000,257000,258000,259000,260000,261000,262000,263000,264000,265000,266000,267000,268000,269000,270000,271000,272000,273000,274000,275000,276000,277000,278000,279000,280000,NEW YORK,0,N6UJ9A013230,toto

my code in jupiter:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
df = pd.read_csv('dummy_new.csv')
df['NUMBER'] = '"' + df['NUMBER'].astype(str) + '"'
df.to_csv('final.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a subset of your test data:

```
      N  empty          NUMBER  ('Something Something', 'sumAve')
0          NaN             "0"                               1000
1          NaN             "0"                              41000
2          NaN             "1"                              81000
3          NaN    "1234567890"                             121000
4          NaN  "123456789012"                             161000
5          NaN     "234567891"                             201000
6          NaN   "23456789012"                             241000
```

I ran your current code with a couple modifications

```
df['NUMBER'] = '"' + df['NUMBER'].astype(str) + '"'

# save as .txt instead of .csv, use the csv.QUOTE_NOTE in the quoting parameter, and set the escapechar to `|`
df.to_csv('final.txt', index=None, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar='|')
```

This will keep the '"' from becoming triple quotes.

Also, if you're using Excel to read this in, make sure you set the text qualifier to a single quote rather than a double to ensure that the numbers are read in as text.

[image: excel]

Reference [pandas to_csv output quoting issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21147058/pandas-to-csv-output-quoting-issue)

Comment: yes, I used it. Didn't work. I have another column that I need to quote automatically. And when I use QUOTE_NONE I need some skip_character that doesn't work in my code.

Comment: Can you supply some sample data so I can test it? Also, what version of `pandas` are you using? I'm using `0.23.4`

Comment: Around 30 minutes, I need to change it just a little, because it is confidential. Thank you.

Comment: https://mega.nz/#!TJYz3aDY!i--0qRACUN_zvUBbJCmFYXQ3qVamYZUZZ9IhKRcImd8
here is my csv and .ipynb

Comment: Can you post 5 rows of it in `code-format` in the question? Not supposed to use links.

Comment: @АндрейГлухов please see my edits and let me know if this works

Comment: I open this file by notepad, not excel. I did it before too. It doesn't work for me because of escapechar So it should be double quotes on some headings like "('Something Something', 'sumAve')" without any "|" because our corporate programme will not read it