# quotations in arrays of strings in pandas to_csv read_csv on jupyter

Tags: python, pandas

This post is a follow up from [pandas to_csv output quoting issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21147058/pandas-to-csv-output-quoting-issue).

Say, I create a data frame with text data. This text data is stored as a list of strings:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: text = ['this', 'is', '"out text"']
   ...: df_pre = pd.DataFrame(index=['1'], columns=['one','two'])
   ...: df_pre.loc['1','one'] = 123
   ...: df_pre.loc['1','two'] = text
```

Inspecting the column of the **pre**-read data frame:

```
In [3]: df_pre
Out[3]: 
   one                     two
1  123  [this, is, "out text"]

In [4]: df_pre.two.iloc[0]
Out[4]: ['this', 'is', '"out text"']
```

This exactly how I'd like it: `df.two` is a list of strings, and the quotations within string element are preserved.

But when I write and then read the df as a csv:

```
In [5]: df_pre.to_csv('foo.txt', index=False)
In [5]: df_post = pd.read_csv('foo.txt')
```

I see that `df.two` has been differently represented, so that there additional quotations now in the **post**-read data frame:

```
In [6]: df_post
Out[6]: 
   one                           two
0  123  ['this', 'is', '"out text"']
```

And here:

```
In [7]: df_post.two.iloc[0]
Out[7]: '[\'this\', \'is\', \'"out text"\']'
```

The problem with this is that, if I'd like to loop through each string element in the `df.two` column for each row, I have to contend with the additional quotations wrapping each element. So, if I wanted to count how many times 'this' occurs, using the **post** data frame, I'd get 0.

My questions:

1. Why does this happen?
2. How can I prevent it from happening?

I've experimented with all levels of quoting (i.e., [0,3]) but to no avail. My goal is to work with many rows of text data (tokenizing, stemming, etc) and save work in a csv format for later manipulation.

---

As a follow-up, I want **post** to look like **pre**:

**Pre** (without additional quotations):

```
In [8]: df_pre
Out[8]: 
   one                     two
1  123  [this, is, "out text"]
```

**Post** (with additional quotations):

```
In [9]: df_post
Out[9]: 
   one                           two
0  123  ['this', 'is', '"out text"']
```

---

**Solution**

```
df_post.two = df_post.two.apply(eval)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSV needs to be able to store the data in a way that it can be loaded back in, so it [escapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) the characters that have meaning (notably the commas, which are the default column delimiters, and the single quotes, which would otherwise terminate your string).

To convert it back from the escaped format, you can use eval:

```
input = '[\'this\', \'is\', \'"out text"\']'
output = eval(input)
```

That operation can also be performed on an entire column of a dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for this. My struggle is not that escape characters remain unconverted. Instead, I'm struggling with the fact that the additional single quotations around each element are retained when I read data frame back in from a csv file. Pre: `[this, is, "out text"]`, Post `['this', 'is', '"out text"']`.