# Pandas `to_csv` unable to set quotes

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do what some of the answers in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21147058/pandas-to-csv-output-quoting-issue) suggest, but when I set

```
out.to_csv('somefile.txt', index=False, header=False, sep="\t",
           quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

I get the error `NameError: name 'csv' is not defined`. What am I doing wrong here?

I'm running pandas `0.24.1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add namespace `csv`:

```
import csv

out.to_csv('somefile.txt', index=False, header=False, sep="\t",
           quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

Or set value `3`, number is from [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#quoting-compression-and-file-format):

> **quoting** : int or csv.QUOTE_* instance, default 0
>   Control field quoting behavior per csv.QUOTE_* constants. Use one of QUOTE_MINIMAL (0), QUOTE_ALL (1), QUOTE_NONNUMERIC (2) or **QUOTE_NONE** (**3**).

```
out.to_csv('somefile.txt', index=False, header=False, sep="\t",
           quoting=3)
```

Comment: Well I feel silly now... But shouldn't this not be needed? Note that this is only necessary because of the quotation option.

Comment: @Sosi - Not tested, how working alternative solution?

Comment: both work quite well :)