# Remove double quotes while printing string in dataframe to text file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe which contains one column with multiple strings. Here is what the data looks like:

```
    Value
    EU-1050-22345,201908 XYZ DETAILS, CD_123_123;CD_123_124,2;1
```

There are almost 100,000 such rows in the dataframe. I want to write this data into a text file.

For this, I tried the following:

```
    df.to_csv(filename, header=None,index=None,mode='a')
```

But I am getting the entire string in quotes when I do this. The output I obtain is:

```
    "EU-1050-22345,201908 XYZ DETAILS, CD_123_123;CD_123_124,2;1"
```

But what I want is:

```
    EU-1050-22345,201908 XYZ DETAILS, CD_123_123;CD_123_124,2;1 -> No Quotes
```

I also tried this:

```
    df.to_csv(filename,header=None,index=None,mode='a',
               quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

However, I get an error that an escapechar is required. If i add escapechar='/' into the code, I get '/' in multiple places (but no quotes). I don't want the '/' either.

Is there anyway I can remove the quotes while writing into a text file WITHOUT adding any other escape characters ?

Answer (score 4):

Based on OP's comment, I believe the semicolon is messing things up. I no longer have unwanted `\` if using tabs to delimit csv.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col'])
df.loc[0] = "EU-1050-22345,201908 XYZ DETAILS, CD_123_123;CD_123_124,2;1"
df.to_csv("out.csv", sep="\t", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar="",  escapechar="")
```

Original Answer:

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21147058/pandas-to-csv-output-quoting-issue), you need to specify `escapechar="\\"` to use `csv.QUOTE_NONE`.

Have you tried:

`df.to_csv("out.csv", sep=",", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar="",  escapechar="\\")`

Comment: @Gary I think the semicolons are messing things up. Is it ok to use a tab instead of comma delimiter?

Comment: Unfortunatly no. The system I pass the file to needs it in this format for their scripts to work. For the time being, I am printing the file with the quotes and removing them manually by using 'replace all'. I can't figure out a better way to solve it.

Comment: @Gary try `escapechar = "" `

Comment: I tried that too! Again, I get an error that an escapechar is required. As you mentioned, I believe the format of the text is in a way that messes file writing up. Unfortunately, I really can't change that!

Comment: @Gary that's so weird because it works for me right now, but maybe the sample df I'm creating is still different from what you're working with

Comment: Could be,because I still get the error 'Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set'. My df row is exactly like this - ' EU-1050-22345,201908 XYZ DETAILS, CD_123_123;CD_123_124,2;1 '

Comment: Didn't realize you were appending to a csv file, so I tried it and got the same escapechar error. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to reproduce that error. I'm wondering if the error comes if you are trying to append to a csv file without the escapechar set. Does the answer work if you're overwriting/creating new csv file instead of appending?

Comment: I tried changing the mode from append to write and still get the same error. When I change the escapechar to '\\', I noticed that the escape char pops up wherever a comma is present in my row. I guess to_csv considers ',' as its default delimiter and tries to escape when it encounters it. That's just my guess though!

Comment: Do you get an error if you run my exact code above? If not, then I'm not working with the same data as you. It would help if you can provide the code to create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: As you suggested earlier, sep=',' will not work. I changed it to sep="\t" and now the quotes are gone.

df.to_csv("out.csv", sep="\t", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar="",  escapechar="")

There does not seem to be a change in format either. I overlooked the 'sep' detail earlier. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to write a df to a csv using a single space as the separator and get the "quotes" around strings removed by replacing existing in-string spaces in the dataframe with non-breaking spaces before I wrote it as as csv.

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: str(x).replace(' ', u"\u00A0"))

df.to_csv(outpath+filename, header=True, index=None, sep=' ', mode='a')
```

I couldn't use a tab delimited file for what I was writing output for, though that solution also works using additional keywords to df.to_csv(): `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar="", escapechar="")`