# with python from csv to text files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, csv

I am trying to wrtie two txtfiles ( Test_8.txt and Test_9.txt ) from the csvfile. 
From row COL4 i am getting single and double quotes and '['.

how can i get rid of them?

### csvfie:

```
NR;COL1;COL2;COL3;COL4;COL5;COL6;COL7;REMARK

Test_9;96;0;4.26;4;5.25;-0.01;1;Test_9 tested, python

Test_9;96;0;4.26;4;11.75;2.35;1;Test_9 tested, python

Test_9;96;0;4.26;4;-3;-3;0.9;Test_9 tested, python

Test_8;95;0;4.25;3;4.75;-0.11;1;Test_8 tested, python

Test_8;95;0;4.25;3;-3;-3;0.9;Test_8 tested, python

Test_8;95;0;4.25;3;16.5;4.26;1;Test_8 tested, python

Test_8;95;0;4.25;3;12.751;2.861;1;Test_8 tested, python
```

### Expected ouput:

```
TYPE    1.0
NR  Test_8

COL1    95

COL2    0
COL3    4.250

COL4    3  
-3.000  -3.000  0.900
4.750   -0.110  1.000
12.751  2.861   1.000
16.500  4.260   1.000

REMARK
Test_8 tested
with python
```

### mycode:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None 
df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Desktop\test_map\test\mycsv_v1.csv',sep=';',index_col='NR')

df['COL3'] = df['COL3'].map('{:,.3f}'.format)

df['COL5'] = df['COL5'].map('{:,.3f}'.format)
df['COL6'] = df['COL6'].map('{:,.3f}'.format)
df['COL7'] = df['COL7'].map('{:,.3f}'.format)

ans = [[x,pd.DataFrame(y)] for x, y in df.groupby(df.index, as_index=True)]
#print ans

for table in ans:
    line1=table[1].iloc[0]
    #print line1
    line1['TYPE']=1.0
    line1['NR']=table[0]

    col567=table[1][['COL5','COL6','COL7']].sort_values(by=['COL5'], ascending=True)
    print col567

    for row in range(len(col567)):
        #print row
        line1[str(col567.values[row])[1:-1]] = None

    line1['']=None

    col8=table[1]['REMARK'].str.split(',')[0]
    col8=table[1]['REMARK'].str.split(', ')[1]
    line1['REMARK']=str(col8.values[0])
    line1['REMARK']=str(col8.values[1])


    line1=line1[['TYPE', 'NR','','COL1','', 'COL2','', 'COL3', 'COL4', 
             str(col567.values[0:]), '', 'REMARK\n', col8.values[0],col8.values[1]]]


    line1.to_csv(table[0]+'.txt',sep='\t')
```

### myoutput;

```
TYPE    1.0
NR  Test_8

COL1    95

COL2    0

COL3    4.250
COL4    3
"[['-3.000' '-3.000' '0.900']
 ['12.751' '2.861' '1.000']
 ['16.500' '4.260' '1.000']
 ['4.750' '-0.110' '1.000']]"   

"REMARK
"   
Test_8 tested   
python
```

Comment: You should add your current output to the question.

Comment: Sort of unclear what you are trying to achieve, you can go ahead and add detail  as to the part that you want to extract to the respective txt files from the CSV

Comment: @xvan Thank you i have added my output

Comment: don't use `str()` but create more complex code to convert list to string.

Comment: @rohitkeshav, yes, my goal is to get two txtfiles ( Test_8.txt and Test_9.txt ) from the csv

Comment: @furas thank you, can you give some example so that i can understand. i think some thing is going in that loop. i am not getting the list sorted also.

Comment: for example use `" ".join()` - ie. `" ".join(["A", "B", "C"])`  gives `A B C` but `str(["A", "B", "C"])` gives `['A', 'B', 'C']`. If you have many rows then you need `for`-loop to format every row separatelly.

Comment: You're printing a list of lists of strings, That's what you're seeing : python's default formatting. We can't know what output you're expecting.

Comment: @ furas, and @ xvan please amend the script. so that i can inderstand because I am not expert in python

Comment: @xvan, i have added my output please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want text without `[]` and `quota` then don't use `str()` and defalt formatting but create own funcion to format it. You can use `" ".join()` and `for`-loop for this

Example code

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([['-3.000', '-3.000', '0.900'],
 ['12.751', '2.861', '1.000'],
 ['16.500', '4.260', '1.000'],
 ['4.750', '-0.110', '1.000']])

print('--- default format ---')
text = str(data)
print(text)

print('--- own format ---')
text = ''
for row in data:
    text += ' '.join(row) + '\n'
print(text)
```

Result:

```
--- default format ---
[['-3.000' '-3.000' '0.900']
 ['12.751' '2.861' '1.000']
 ['16.500' '4.260' '1.000']
 ['4.750' '-0.110' '1.000']]

--- own format ---
-3.000 -3.000 0.900
12.751 2.861 1.000
16.500 4.260 1.000
4.750 -0.110 1.000
```

---

**BTW:** You need to convert `col567.values[0:]`

```
print(str(col567.values[0:]))

text = ''
for row in col567.values[0:]:
    text += " ".join(row) + '\n'
print(text)
```

And use this `text` in

```
line1=line1[['TYPE', 'NR','','COL1','', 'COL2','', 'COL3', 'COL4', 
         text, '', 'REMARK\n', col8.values[0],col8.values[1]]]
```

I tried to run your code but it has many mistakes and it never works.

---

Example code which use string-formating

I use `io.StringIO` only to emulate file with data but you use `pd.read_csv`

BTW: I had to change some elements beacuse to get correctly sorted data they have to be integer/float values not strings `{:,.3f}`

```
import os
import pandas as pd

pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None 

#df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Desktop\test_map\test\mycsv_v1.csv',sep=';',index_col='NR')

text = u'''NR;COL1;COL2;COL3;COL4;COL5;COL6;COL7;REMARK
Test_9;96;0;4.26;4;5.25;-0.01;1;Test_9 tested, python
Test_9;96;0;4.26;4;11.75;2.35;1;Test_9 tested, python
Test_9;96;0;4.26;4;-3;-3;0.9;Test_9 tested, python
Test_8;95;0;4.25;3;4.75;-0.11;1;Test_8 tested, python
Test_8;95;0;4.25;3;-3;-3;0.9;Test_8 tested, python
Test_8;95;0;4.25;3;16.5;4.26;1;Test_8 tested, python
Test_8;95;0;4.25;3;12.751;2.861;1;Test_8 tested, python'''

import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep=';', index_col='NR')

df['COL3'] = df['COL3'].map('{:,.3f}'.format)
#df['COL5'] = df['COL5'].map('{:,.3f}'.format)
#df['COL6'] = df['COL6'].map('{:,.3f}'.format)
#df['COL7'] = df['COL7'].map('{:,.3f}'.format)

ans = df.groupby(df.index, as_index=True)

for table in ans:
    line1 = table[1].iloc[0]

    col567 = table[1][['COL5','COL6','COL7']].sort_values(by=['COL5'], ascending=True)
    col567_text = '\n'.join(' '.join('{:,.3f}'.format(item) for item in row) for row in col567.values[0:])        

    col8 = table[1]['REMARK'][0].split(', ')

    text = '''TYPE    {type_}
NR  {nr}

COL1    {col1}

COL2    {col2}
COL3    {col3}

COL4    {col4}
{col567}

REMARK
{remark1}
{remark2}'''.format(
    type_ = 1.0,
    nr = table[0],
    col1 = table[1]['COL1'][0],
    col2 = table[1]['COL2'][0],
    col3 = table[1]['COL3'][0],
    col4 = table[1]['COL4'][0],
    col567 = col567_text,
    remark1 = col8[0],
    remark2 = col8[1],
)    


    print(text)

    with open(table[0]+'.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(text)
```

Comment: Thank you, I got your point, But i dont know where and how can i use it in my script? can you change it my script?

Comment: use `print()` to see what you have in variables - you will see which one have data which you need to change and then assign data in own format.

Comment: probably you have to change `str(col567.values[0:])` - check `print( str(col567.values[0:]) )`

Comment: @ furas i get this result
 "TYPE 1.0
NR Test_8
 
COL1 95
 
COL2 0
 
COL3 4.250
COL4 3
"COL5 COL6 COL7" 
 
"REMARK
" 
Test_8 tested 
python

Comment: i need to get the values of COL5, COL6 and COL7. but i am not getting it

Comment: did you used my code with `text = ...` and use `text` in line `line1=line1[[...]]` ? it formats `col567.values[0:]` in different way. Maybe you use different code and you create other `text` with different values. Frankly, I tried to run your code from question and it raise error. It seems like you put code which can't work - and maybe you run totally different code.

Comment: i still get begin and end of double quotes   "-3.000 -3.000 0.900
12.751 2.861 1.000
16.500 4.260 1.000
4.750 -0.110 1.000
" 
 
"REMARK
"

Comment: do you know , why the rows are not getting sorted? i dont get any error

Comment: it is because there is `\n` which need to be in `" "` because normally CVS use `\n` to separate rows. It seems you would have to create 3 separated rows in `line1`. The same with `REMARK\n` - you will have to create two rows `REMARK` and empty row.

Comment: maybe format all in one string and save it as normal text file - not CSV file - using standard `open()`, `write()`, `close()`.

Comment: is it possible to remove this \n ?

Comment: to remove it you would have to put it as 3 separated rows (every row without `\n') instead of one string with '\n'`. And then it will add `\n` as row's separator. OR create one string with all text and save it as text file using standard `open()`, `write()`, `close()`

Comment: BTW: you could use also string formatting - `"{} {}".format(var1, var2)` - or `f-string` - `f"{var1} {var2}"` to format text which you want to save in file.

Comment: sorry to tell, now i lost completly

Comment: dont' use `list.to_csv()` but create string with all values and use `open()`, `write()`, `close()` - you will have better control how you format string which you will save.

Comment: this is good, can you post a basic format so that i can understand and can work

Comment: i have got a error at line 56 `NameError: name 'col8' is not defined`

Comment: I moved `col8 = table[1]['REMARK'][0].split(', ')` to correct place and now it works

Comment: Thank you, one last thing, instead of text i want to path to the csvfile. is this possible?

Comment: use normally  `df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\...', ...)`  instead of `text` and `pd.read_csv(io.String(text), ...)` I used `text` and `io.String()` only to emulate file in memory so everyone could run it.

Comment: should i change this also   "text = '''TYPE    {type_}"

Comment: no, this `text = '''TYPE {type_}` is different text - you need it.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are super. you helped me a lot with this .

Answer (score 0):

You're printing a numpy.array of numpy.arrays.
The default formatting is a list of lists.

You could add your own formatting using list comprehension and string `join()`.

```
col567_fmt = '\n'.join( [ '\t'.join(x) for x in col567.values[0:] ] )
line1=line1[['TYPE', 'NR','','COL1','', 'COL2','', 'COL3', 'COL4', 
         col567_fmt, '', 'REMARK\n', col8.values[0],col8.values[1]]]
```

Also, if you want to print using `to_csv()` you'll need to disable quotation. See replies to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21147058/1477064)

Comment: @ xvan, i get the rows not sorted and got double quotes at the begin and end
"-3.000 -3.000 0.900
12.751 2.861 1.000
16.500 4.260 1.000
4.750 -0.110 1.000
"

Comment: sorted rows are important in that txt files

Comment: The rows are printed with col567.values[0:] order, with the same order you requested. I just tested it on python2.

Comment: The quotes are added because of the line breaks by the to_csv() function. Check if you can remove them as suggested on the last paragraph of my reply. Basically try this: import csv
line1.to_csv(table[0]+'.txt',sep='\t',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

Comment: i tried but got `TypeError: to_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'quoting'`

Comment: i mean `sort_values(by=['COL5'], ascending=True)` is not doing anything.