# Output table from SQL into csv format and add quotation marks around a column

Tags: python, sql, csv, quotation-marks

I am want to output a table from SQL as csv but I want to add quotation marks around the last column.

The name of the table I have in SQL is dbo.temp_table:

[image]

The output I want is a csv file, that when opened in notepad, the last column has double quotes:

[image]

When I use the below python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd 
import xlsxwriter
import csv


sql_conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={DRIVER NAME}; SERVER=DATABASE_NAME; DATABASE=MY_DATABASE; Trusted_Connection=yes') 

query = "select * from dbo.temp_table"     
                                       
df = pd.read_sql(query, sql_conn)


file_out = 'C:\\Desktop\\TestFolder\\TestFile.csv'

df.to_csv(file_out, index = False, header=True)
```

I get this output (when the csv is opened in notepad):

[image]

I have also tried adding the quotation marks in the actual query in the python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd 
import xlsxwriter
import csv


sql_conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={DRIVER NAME}; SERVER=DATABASE_NAME; DATABASE=MY_DATABASE; Trusted_Connection=yes') 

query = """select [name]
        ,'"' + [code] + '"' AS [code]
        from dbo.temp_table    """  
                                       
df = pd.read_sql(query, sql_conn)


file_out = 'C:\\Desktop\\TestFolder\\TestFile.csv'

df.to_csv(file_out, index = False, header=True)
```

but the output I get has 3 double quotes in the last column:

[image]

I think a solution could be to actually add the quotation marks within the python code but none of the questions I have looked at online seem to answer my question. I'd really appreciate some help.

Comment: `import csv; df.to_csv(file_out, index = False, header=True, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)` would put quotes around both columns.

Comment: Or you could add them in SQL like you tried and do `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE`, but this comes with the risk that if you have any data that needs quoting it won't happen. It will, however, produce exactly the output you are looking for.

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21147058/pandas-to-csv-output-quoting-issue

Comment: @StevenRumbalski thank you very much, the last option worked! Appreciate the help.

Comment: @IoaTzimas thank you too for the link!